What were Hollow's ultimate intentions for Kamen?
In season 1, episode 1 (S01E01) of Scavenger's Reign, the human character Kamen meets an enigmatic creature later referred to as Hollow (Netflix episode synopsis, S01E02).
At first Hollow seems to treat Kamen as a curiosity or pet, saving him form several potentially dangerous situation.
Hollow then uses Kamen to source food for him, particularly meat (S01E03).
Later Hollow absorbs Kamen, and appears to keep him dormant - but physically intact - inside its body. Feeding him through an umbilical tube and sustaining his life (S01E05).
From then onwards, Hollow seemingly becomes possessive of Kamen, attacking and killing/destroying anyone and anything that might lead to them being separated, or which might link him to his previous life. For example, destroying Levi when it hums a song the reminds Kamen of his late wife (S01E06) and destroying the miner's shuttle that could potentially rescue Kamen (S01E07).
As Hollow had no use for Kamen as a food provider from S01E05 onwards, and seemed to have no physical or psychological need for him, why did it keep him around, and what were it's intentions towards him?
